# Laravel 4 magic method __call replacement in controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am building a permission system and I need to have granularity over every method of every controller, so i was thinking to implment this with the __call magic method on my base controller like so:

```
public function __call($name, $args)
{       
    if ( $this->checkPermission() )
    {

        call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);
    }
    else 
    {
        // handle error
    }

}
```

But apparantly this does not work in Laravel 4. How would be right approach to emulate that __call magic method ? I thought of before filters but they are not handed the called method name and arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__call` is a magic method that is called when the method does not exist on the class. So I don't see how that would help you.

My suggestion would be to use a before filter, as you do have access to the current route and request.

```
Route::filter('permissions', function($route, $request)
{

});
```

You could then use methods like `$route->getAction()` to extract the controller and method that will be called and `$route->getParameters()` or `$request->segment()` to get the arguments.

Just register all routes inside a group that has this filter applied.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'permissions'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function() { });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I got confused about __call by this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/3716649/